# Absurd problem(s) in exercise set on products of families of classes?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, reference-request

I asked a question last night for help proceeding in a proof; the response I received implied the question was an absurdity. This wasn't entirely shocking to me- I'm working in the Dover edition of Charles Pinter's "A Book of Set Theory," whose exposition I find sufficiently rigorous and clear, but whose exercises (I've come to find, in part through this forum) are often erroneous. Does anyone have a similar experience with this book? Can anyone suggest a better book- at least for its exercise selection? I'm considering Hrbacek & Jech's "Introduction to Set Theory."

For instance, here is an exercise included in the problem set for the chapter on products of families of classes, which seems ludicrous:

[As written]
"In the next three exercises (exercises 4, 5, and 6), assume the following:
$\cup_{i\in I}A_i = \cup_{j\in J}B_j = X$.

6. Let $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ and $\{B_j\}_{j\in J}$ be families of classes. Prove the following:

   a) $(\prod_{i\in I}A_i) \cap (\prod_{j\in J}B_j) = \prod_{(i,j)\in I\times J}(A_i \cap B_j)$.

   b) $(\prod_{i\in I}A_i) \cup (\prod_{j\in J}B_j) = \prod_{(i,j)\in I\times J}(A_i \cup B_j)$."

Can anyone please re-confirm that this problem is nonsensical, and perhaps provide any alternatives for exercise sets?

Comment: You might want to try [this](https://realnotcomplex.com) link if you're looking for more references

Comment: You are right, this exercise does not make sense. The types of the sets do not match up. For example the intersection on the left in (a) will be empty if $J \neq I$. Even if $J = I$ then still the types on the left and right of the equality sign don't match. As to suggestions for books: I have not read Jech and Hrbacek's book, but I know that Jech's more advanced book "Set Theory" is very well-known and has a good reputation.

Comment: @Mark: Jech's "Set Theory" is a more advanced book, of course.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes of course. I did not mean that book as a recommendation for OP to read now, but it is an indication that Jech is a good author.

Answer (score 1):

Exercise.
Let {A$_n$}$_{n.in.J}$, {B$_n$}$_{n.in.J}$
be two collections of sets.
Prove $\Pi_{n.in.J} A_n \cap \Pi_{n.in.J} A_n =
\Pi_{n.in.J} (A_n \cap B_n)$.
Give a counterexample for
$\Pi_{n.in.J} A_n \cup \Pi_{n.in.J} B_n 
= \Pi_{n.in.J} (A_n \cup B_n)$.

Comment: Ironically, the proof your requesting was the previous problem in the text (#5). One strange matter is that, formally, #5 requires the axiom of choice to prove- which hasn't been covered up to this point in the text. Also, it makes the problem I posted originally even more questionable- it can't be justified as a typo anymore.

Comment: As for a counterexample for the analogous statement regarding unions of families of classes: consider $\{x_n\}\in \Pi_{n\in J}(A_n \cup B_n)$ such that $x_n\in B_n$ if $n=2k,$where$k\in \Bbb N$, otherwise $x_n\in A_n$. Thus, each element in $J$ is mapped to an element of $(A_n \cup B_n)$, In general, though, $(A_n \cup B_n) \subsetneq A_n$ and $(A_n \cup B_n) \subsetneq B_n$. Hence, the function is not necessarily a member of either product on the L.H.S.